# ActionBar navigation tabs showing fragments on top of each other

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an ActionBar with various navigation tabs on it. I am finding that in some circumstances (I do not understand them fully) fragment content is appearing on top of fragment content.

i.e. I visit one tab, then click a button that swaps the fragment for another, then click one of the other tabs, and the fragment content from the initial tab click is visible under the new fragment content. It seems I've built an app where it's possible to use the navigation to place fragment content on top of other fragment content, which is not what I want.

How can I ensure that when updating fragment content, the old content is removed correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I ensure that when updating fragment content, the old content is removed correctly?

You are the one creating the `FragmentTransaction` that is being applied by the `TabListener`. In that `FragmentTransaction`, you are telling Android what fragments to add, what fragments to remove, etc. Make sure you are setting up the `FragmentTransaction` objects with the business rules you want.

Comment: Thanks Mark. I had fragments on the back stack that were causing the problem. I removed calls to addToBackStack() and it's all fixed.